# What am I doing wrong. tune_grid cubist failed

Tags: r, tidymodels

Tried to follow the instructions to generate the engine, workflow, then the recipe.
The part which i can't seem to get right is to tune the cubist model. appreciate your guidance.

**These untuned models work**;

```r
#untuned rf
rf_model <- 
  rand_forest(trees = 1000
              # ,mtry = 30
              # ,min_n = 3
              ) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger", 
             num.threads = parallel::detectCores(), 
             importance = "permutation") %>% 
  set_mode("regression")

rf_wflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(df_recipe) %>% 
  add_model(rf_model)

system.time(rf_fit <- rf_wflow %>% fit(data = train))

# build untuned cubist model
cubist_mod <-
  cubist_rules(
    committees = 100,
    neighbors = 9
    # max_rules = integer(1)
  ) %>%
  set_engine("Cubist") %>%
  set_mode("regression")

cubist_wflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(cube_recipe) %>%
  add_model(cubist_mod)

system.time(final_cb_mod <- cubist_wflow %>% fit(data = train))

summary(final_cb_mod$fit)
```

**And the tuned version of the rf works too**

```r
#tune ranger
tune_spec <- rand_forest(
  mtry = tune(),
  trees = 1000,
  min_n = tune()) %>%
  set_mode("regression") %>%
  set_engine("ranger")

tune_wf <- 
  workflow() %>%
  add_model(tune_spec) %>% 
  add_recipe(df_recipe)

set.seed(234)
trees_folds <- vfold_cv(train)

rf_grid <- grid_regular(
  mtry(range = c(10, 30)),
  min_n(range = c(2, 8)),
  levels = 5
)

set.seed(345)
system.time(
  tune_res <- tune_grid(
    tune_wf,
    resamples = trees_folds,
    grid = rf_grid,
    control =
      control_grid(#save_pred = T,
                   pkgs = c('tm', 'stringr'))
  )
)
```

**But when i tried to tune cubist, it generated this error. My cubist tune code is as below**

```r
Warning message:
All models failed. See the `.notes` column.

> car_tune_res$.notes[1]
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  .notes                                                                                                                                             
  <chr>                                                                                                                                              
1 preprocessor 1/1: Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]): contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

**the tuning of cubist**

```r
#tune cubist
cb_grid <- expand.grid(committees = c(1, 10, 50, 100), neighbors = c(1, 5, 7, 9))

set.seed(8226)

cubist_mod <-
  cubist_rules(neighbors = tune(), committees = tune()) %>%
  set_engine("Cubist") %>% 
  set_mode("regression")

tuned_cubist_wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(cubist_mod) %>% 
  add_recipe(cube_recipe)

system.time(
  car_tune_res <-
    cubist_mod %>%
    tune_grid(
      price ~ .,
      resamples = trees_folds,
      grid = cb_grid,
      control =
        control_grid(#save_pred = T,
          pkgs = c('tm', 'stringr'))
    )
)
```

**added the recipe for reference**

```r
int_var <- train %>% select(where(is.integer)) %>% colnames()
int_var <- c(int_var,'geo_dist')
# excl_var <- c('url')

add_words <- 
  str_extract(train$url,'(?<=-).*(?=-)') %>% 
  str_extract_all(.,'[[:alpha:]]+') %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  str_to_lower()

df_recipe <-
  recipe(price ~ .,data = train) %>%
  step_geodist(lat = lat, lon = long, log = FALSE,
               ref_lat = 144.946457, ref_lon = -37.840935, # Melb CBD
               is_lat_lon = FALSE) %>%
  step_rm('suburb') %>% 
  step_rm('prop_type') %>% 
  step_rm('url') %>% 
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>%
  # step_rm('desc') %>% 
  step_mutate(desc_raw = desc) %>%
  step_textfeature(desc_raw) %>%
  step_rename_at(
    starts_with("textfeature_"),
    fn = ~ gsub("textfeature_desc_raw_", "", .)) %>% 
  step_mutate(desc = str_to_lower(desc)) %>% 
  step_mutate(desc = removeNumbers(desc)) %>% 
  step_mutate(desc = removePunctuation(desc)) %>% 
  step_tokenize(desc) %>%  #engine = "spacyr"
  step_stopwords(desc, stopword_source = 'snowball') %>%
  step_stopwords(desc, custom_stopword_source = add_words) %>%
  step_tokenfilter(desc, max_tokens = 1e3) %>% #, max_tokens = tune()
  step_tfidf(desc) %>% #lda_models = lda_model
  step_novel(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_YeoJohnson(all_of(!!int_var), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes(), one_hot = TRUE) %>%
  step_normalize(all_of(!!int_var))

#dimension reduction due to the sparse matrix
cube_recipe <- 
  df_recipe %>% 
  step_pca(matches("school|tfidf_desc"),threshold = .8) %>% #|lda_desc
  step_rm(starts_with("school")) %>%
  step_rm(starts_with("lda_desc"))
```

Comment: The error you are getting is happening in the recipe. Can you show the code you used to generate `df_recipe`.

Comment: @EmilHvitfeldt recipe added. I had 2, one for ranger (kept the sparse matrix). The other applied dimension reduction due to the limitation of cubist not coping. I'm sure there is a lot of improvements there. appreciate your guidance. I've tried to follow your work as examples

Comment: Try running prep(df_recipe) %>% bake(new_data = NULL). This should hopefully give the same error, then run traceback() to see which step gave the issue.

Comment: I could produce the dataframe after the feature engineer via recipe for both df_recipe and cube_recipe. when i find the time, will try to tune cubist without using workflow. ie. juice the tables and feed tube_grid for cubist. cause that was successfully done prior this. I wanted to recycle the code and utilise the workflow. thanks